# No echo for expect send command

Tags: expect

Got a license agreement which I want to process in expect.
I have the following code

```
{
  /usr/bin/expect << EOD
  log_user 0
  set timeout 20
  spawn -noecho "${filename}" > /dev/null 2>&1

  stty -echo;
  expect {
      "Press Enter to view the End User License Agreement" {
          send "\r"
          exp_continue
      }
      "More" {
          send " "
          exp_continue
      }
      "Do you accept the End User License Agreement?" {
          log_user 0
          send "y\r"
          log_user 0
      }
  }
  interact
  expect eof
EOD
}
```

Running this I get the following output:

```
y
```

It is working fine, but I want to get no output from the expect at all.
My goal is to not echo the send command.
As you can see I have already tried to use the `log_user` and `stty` to get this done, but with no luck.
Before using this extra bits in the code, I could see the whole license text on screen. With `log_user 0` this is now not showing anymore.
But I still got the `y` from the last send command, which I'm not able to not echo on screen.

Any advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With `stty -echo` itself sufficient to hide the output. But, I am not sure what's wrong with that.

Anyway, try this.

```
"Do you accept the End User License Agreement?" {
    send "y\r"
    log_user 0
    expect *
}
log_user 1
send \r; # This is optional
interact
```

Comment: Still the same output